# Twitter API Could not find list

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I created a list on twitter, when i try to get this list, API return is:
Could not find list with id: [1497056174981758978]

I can find another lists but i need that one:
https://twitter.com/i/lists/1497056174981758978

client.get_list(id=1497056174981758978)

Out[78]: Response(data=None, includes={}, errors=[{'value': '1497056174981758978', 'detail': 'Could not find list with id: [1497056174981758978].', 'title': 'Not Found Error', 'resource_type': 'list', 'parameter': 'id', 'resource_id': '1497056174981758978', 'type': 'https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/resource-not-found'}], meta={})

Thx for your help guys

Comment: Then I would say there is no such list.  What makes you think there is?  Your link comes up with a "not found" error.

Comment: Thank you Tim, i realized that my account is protected and because of that, the lists that i created is also protected. 
So i just switch to unprotected account and i am able to see my list :)

Comment: Where in the twitter settings did you make this change? I have the same issue. Actually nevermind - in my case tweets were unprotected already.